# Javascript alert getElementsByClassName("x").style.display

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to get the value of "display" through JS sorted by Classes.
My code is:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("codeContainer");
alert(x[0].style.display);
```

The thing is that the alert box is just empty. The call

```
alert(x.length);
```

works great and returns "4". What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: is it set in the css?

Comment: I did not specify [0] and [3] in css, but [1] and [2] are set to display:none;
And alert(x[1].style.display); also returns an empty alert box

Comment: can u show the codeContainer html Element?

Comment: It works in my test-case: https://jsfiddle.net/3br11ese/ for inline-styles. So as @Arvind answered already its not possible to get the style from an external css definition.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, if the element is formatted by external css instead of inline css using style attribute, you are bound to get blank value.

```
alert(x[0].style.display);
```

With inline css:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log('total inputs:', inputs.length);

var bg = inputs[0].style.background;

console.log('background:', bg);
```

```html
<input type='text' style='background:orange' />
```

You need to get the computed style for the same, [getStyle() reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dhtmlcascade4.shtml).

```js
var getStyle = function(el, cssprop) {
  if (el.currentStyle) //IE
    return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
  else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //Firefox
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
  else //try and get inline style
    return el.style[cssprop]
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log('total inputs:', inputs.length);
console.log('color:', getStyle(inputs[0], 'color'));
```

```css
.input {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='input' value='hi' />
<input type='text' class='input' value='hello' />
```

Comment: Using inline css for these divs works for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The property "style.display" is not defined. therefore it returns "empty"

You can try this:

```
alert(x[0].style.display||window.getComputedStyle(x[0],null).getPropertyValue("display"));
```

Answer (score 0):

after the DOM is ready only we should check for the properties. please check the code below.

```
(function(){var x = document.getElementsByClassName("codeContainer");

alert(x[0].style.display);})();
```